# Is there any definition of such functions in lattice theory?

Tags: reference-request, lattice-orders

Let $\mathfrak L$ be a [lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)) and $f:\mathfrak L\to \mathbb R$ be a function. We say that $f$ obeys $\mathfrak L$ if for any $A,B\in \mathfrak L$ we have

$$f(A\vee B)=f(A)+f(B)-f(A\wedge B)$$

I expect that such definition already exists. Any reference or comment is welcome.

Comment: I am curious, what is **Lattice** ? I did a problem like this before, but I don't understand if this and that same.

Comment: This seems to be related to the concept of [additive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_additivity) in measure theory. Notice among their [basic properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_additivity#Basic_properties): $\mu(A \cup B) + \mu(A \cap B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$.

Comment: @MANMAID [Lattice (order)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order))

Comment: @amrsa so it is not what you are saying. I don't see measure theory in that link.

Comment: @MANMAID That link is to the definition of lattice. And I didn't say the name of the definition mesel asked for is additive function, but that it seems related, meaning that it has the same shape. Sometimes names are borrowed from different areas. For example, I've seen a Pythagoras theorem for $n$-dimensional spaces, and I suppose Pythagoras never though about that...

Comment: @amrsa yes you are right, $f$ may be related to additive function. I said that because when I read number theory their was some additive functions, but you mentioned **measure theory**, then I thought that those number theoretic additive functions are not related to measure theory(or may be, my knowledge is very very little.) That why I pointed out measure theory, that all.

Comment: @MANMAID: Is this question to me?

Comment: @mesel My question is what is lattice, but it seems amrsa gave the answer(if that is right.)

Comment: This post on MathOverflow seems to be (to some extent) related: [Additive functions on a lattice](https://mathoverflow.net/q/55515).

Comment: Your definition of a lattice as an analogue of intersection and union makes me think you have [bounded distributive lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice) in mind. Please clarify.

Comment: To be able to make this definition, one does need not require any further property for the lattice to satisfy yet if such definitions are made in some particular lattices, it is also ok for me to in terms of references. Sorry for unclear definition, it is best to give a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a *valuation* on $\mathfrak L$, see [Birkhoff's book](https://books.google.sk/books?hl=sk&id=ePqVAwAAQBAJ&q=valuation#v=snippet&q=valuation&f=false) for more on that.